# XAMPP Mysql can't running on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

Im using XAMPP 7.4 on My Macbook air 2020
i've tried so many ways or command like :

sudo killall mysqld
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

but it keep won't running.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. Open XAMPP -> Services -> MySQL -> Start

or

2. open terminal in your XAMPP (button `Open Terminal`) and restart mysql

```
systemctl restart mysql
```